# Does DROPing a table create a bunch of transactions in the transaction log for all the records being purged?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log, truncate, drop-table

If I have a table with billions of records, is it faster and does it create less data in the transaction log to `TRUNCATE` it first and then `DROP` it or can I just `DROP` it all the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRUNCATE TABLE and DROP TABLE are both metadata-only operations.  They make changes to the system catalog, including which extents are allocated to a particular object.  All these changes are logged.  But the cost is very small, regardless of the size of the table.

The only thing that will create log records for each row is DELETE.

Comment: Cool, that was my understanding, and then the data is purged in an efficient way in chunks to not overload the server memory if I read correctly? Does that mean if I drop a 1 TB table, I don't have to worry about much overhead causing server contention?

Comment: Yes.  Extents do not have to be read to de-allocate them.  There's a list of which extents belong to which objects, and only that list has to be updated.

Comment: ... i.e., the data isn't "purged" per se. It is still on the pages (and can be read by DBCC PAGE). But they are de-allocated and can be re-used.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, you might want to add that space reclamation for larger tables (128+ extents) is deferred. After the drop/truncate commits the metadata changes synchronously, extents marked for deallocation are reclaimed by an asynchronous background thread in batches so that the drop/truncate operation doesn't need to wait.