# Permanently Delete the sql server database table

Tags: sql-server, delete, drop-table

I wanted the remove the table from the sql server database. The table has 500 million records. I don't need the table anymore.

What's the best approach?
Can I use drop table command to delete the table permanently? If yes is this the good approach?
I want to minimize the transaction log file growth or any other issues while I drop the table.
Should I do in off business hours or if the impact is minimal I can it anytime?

SQL server version is both 2017 and 2019.
Databases containing those tables have same compatibility and are in full recovery model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does DROPing a table create a bunch of transactions in the transaction log for all the records being purged?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262230/does-droping-a-table-create-a-bunch-of-transactions-in-the-transaction-log-for-a)

Comment: Thank you so much. really helped

Answer (score 2):

`DROP TABLE` is a minimally logged operation, as already answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262230/does-droping-a-table-create-a-bunch-of-transactions-in-the-transaction-log-for-a).

So, you can go ahead with the `DROP TABLE` operation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification